# how to fix google play services version

Tags: android, google-play-services

Today when I was building a program, I get a problem. This problem is that:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Mert\Desktop\FireBase\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 254

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

My code is:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$GMS_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

If you can answer this problem, it will be perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
> Could not get unknown property 'GMS_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

As the error implies, GMS_VERSION may not be declared anywhere in the script. You should either declare GMS_VERSION variable or directly mention the version instead of using a variable.

```
dependencies {
    def GMS_VERSION = "16.0.8"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$GMS_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

or directly use the version

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8"
```

Comment: are you facing this same issue again or anything new? Can u be more specific about the error?

Comment: Yes same problem. nothing has changed.

Comment: Check if you have used GMS_VERSION somewhere else in the script. Check line 254 as the exception says